# Upgrading to SimplePie 1.3, documentation leaves something to be desired, plus busted my news aggregator

Tags: php, simplepie

I clicked the big download button and uploaded /library and autoloader.php but that was insufficient in switching over to the new codebase. I had previously renamed my old installation, simplepie.old from simplepie.inc but with no simplepie.inc file, my aggregator wouldn't run.

I reread the documentation and switched to using the one file version of the library which I renamed simplepie.inc

This allows my aggregator to run, but my feed of feeds is now blank...  My news aggregator was based off of the News Blocks 2 demo.

[Miniature Painting News Aggregator](http://news.muschamp.ca)

My other uses of SimplePie seem to be functioning after the renaming, but I'm unsure what the autoloader.php is supposed to do.  The documentation still references simplepie.inc

```
require_once('../simplepie.inc');
```

The portion of my news aggregator that is busted is my feed of feeds, I'll have to see what methods I'm calling that either no longer exist or have been renamed. But the upgrade/documentation leaves something to be desired. How am I supposed to use the autoloader.php? Or am I just best using the one file version since that is what all the existing code expects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which part of that page specifically is broken? It seems like it's working to me.

[image: Screenshot of the page]

Regarding the documentation, apologies about that, it hasn't been fully updated yet. Essentially, anywhere you see `simplepie.inc` replace that with `autoloader.php`.

Comment: Yes that last line about replacing simplepie.inc with autoloader.php would probably help, but isn't intuitive. As for my news aggregator I fixed it. The problem is one of three things: 1) bad feeds, 2) XML/text/RSS encoding escaping of characters like & 3) my code not handling garbage in and failing gracefully